# jQuery keyup keyCode doesn't work in Opera

Tags: jquery, opera, keycode

Is it possible that the opera browser ignore the keyCode 40 (arrow down)?

```
 $('#test').keyup(function(e) {
        $('body').append('' + e.keyCode + '');
 })
```

Test it at: http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/454/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use the `autocomplete` attribute, and set it to `off`:

```
<input id="test" value="" autocomplete="off" >
```

Opera uses the arrow down key for auto completion, and may therefore suppress the forwarding of the event.

Working test: http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/455/

Comment: You could also cancel the default action of the key*press* event with event.preventDefault() - http://www.jsfiddle.net/6zsGK/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this does not work (seems like opera does not support it).
Have a look at [this test page from www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) showing you what your broswer detects (keyup is not fired).

Comment: Thank you very much. The page is nice ;).
Keycode 40 works only with keypress or keydown in opera.

Comment: i have this page in my bookmark pane - need it a lot for all those nasty different browsers :)