# Opera, jQuery - prevent notice popup on key up

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, opera, arrow-keys

I'm trying to build a selector box with search results which can be selected using the keyboard. It's not too hard to do - except when it comes to Opera which I can't prevent from popping up an own selector box (wand form settings) on key down, making it impossible to make a choice from mine.

**Here's a little demo:** Type something into the box and try to select from my popup with the arrow down... will work as intended in latest Chrome, for example - won't work in latest Opera.

Opera's my favorite, so I need to find a solution just to satisfiy myselve ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/ujFvn/13/

Thanks for sharing ideas...

Comment: What Opera-selection-box? I get the exact same result in Opera 11.52 as in FF4

Comment: This one [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/operaview.jpg/) - You'll get it when you add something to your "form predefenitions" or what ever they're called...:

Comment: ...it's where you set up your wand, [link](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.00/en/wand.html)

Comment: Ah, that box. Well, I am afraid there is no way out of that. This happens when you hit the arrows? Or what do you mean by "using the keyboard"? You could try preventing standard-action.

Comment: I tried to preventDefault of course... but it does'nt work with key**up**... just found I need to use keydown to prevent that popup, though that'll give me a headake on another peace of code, but anyway... thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [jQuery keyup keyCode doesn't work in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624812/jquery-keyup-keycode-doesnt-work-in-opera)

Soloution: use autocomplete="off"

```
<input id="test" value="" autocomplete="off" >
```

Or if you wan't to keep it clean in JS:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Inside your keyup function.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: e.PreventDefault is obvious, tried that... but as I just found it only works with event key**down** whereas I was using keyup (for some special reasons, but ok, can change that). Damn. Thanks for your answer anyway... (http://jsfiddle.net/ujFvn/15/ works now)